# making graphs with a shell script

Tags: regex, bash, grep

i need to make a graph with numeric values in a time period, the values represent online users in a web page.

the script will be exectued with cron every 30 mins and the needed html file will be downloaded with wget. but there are some yet unanswered questions & problems:

-i need to get just the numeric value from html code (but grep returns the whole line), how can I get only the numeric value? I can get the line with grep, it looks like this:

```
                            Users online: 24 917                    </div>
```

How can I get just the 24917?

-what would be easier? to generate .svg file with the graph, or save values in a .csv file (and generate graph with OOo or something similar). Maybe some other good ideas?

Thanks in advance,

-skazhy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following to get your number:

Set the regular expression:

```
digits='[[:digit:]]+ *[[:digit:]]*'
```

followed by these two lines:

```
num=$(echo $line | grep -Eo "$digits")
num=${num// }
```

or these:

```
# Bash >= 3.2 (syntax may be different for 3.0/3.1)
[[ $line =~ $digits ]]
num=${BASH_REMATCH[@]// }
```

to extract the number from the variable `$line` containing the line in your question.

[Gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info) should be readily available. A few examples of its output can be found [here](http://www.gnuplot.info/screenshots/index.html).

These are from [here](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Gnuplot_diagrams).

[image: example graph] [image: example graph]

Answer (score 0):

Just one process (grep):

```
array=( $(grep whatever filename ) ) && echo  "${array[2]}${array[3]}"
```